# Hello, i need to test this property of Logic Statements, Connectives and Quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

(∃xp(x) → ∃xq(x)) → ∃x(p(x) → q(x))

I have to explain the procedure, starting with (∃xp (x) → ∃xq (x)) until reaching → ∃x (p (x) → q (x)).
To solve this exercise I have taken advantage of this theory:
Recall that given any referential S and conditions p (x),
q (x) appropriate (relative to the elements of S), we have defined ∃xp (x) as
{x ∈ S | p (x)} = ∅ and ∀xp (x) as {x ∈ S | p (x)} = S.
so i take (∃xp(x) → ∃xq(x)) following the theory, I define (∃xp(x) → ∃xq(x)) as {x ∈ S | p(x)} = ∅ → {x ∈ S | q(x)} = ∅

Comment: 'the procedure'?  do you mean a formal proof? Also, you have to remove the starting $\to$ from your goal. Finally, and most importantly: what have you tried yourself?

Comment: formal proof please

Comment: I need to start from the right all the way to the left, testing by definition

Comment: @Brandon, then please show us your effort, up to where you get stuck, and include definitions you've learned that are relevant to this question. Please don't make the mistake of thinking this site is a homework-solution-service.

Comment: From the right to the left?  But in your post you go from the left to the right (which would make more sense).  Also .. what is 'testing by definition'?

Comment: sorry, I made some progress but i was unable to follow (∃xp (x) → ∃xq (x)) → ∃x (p (x)→ q (x)). I'm going to take (∃xp (x) → ∃xq (x)) ↔ {xϵS / p (x)} ≠ ∅ → {xϵS / q (x)} ≠ ∅

Comment: How can this be proven if , on an empty set as a model, the LHS of the "main" implication ($\text{false}\to\text{false}$) is true but the RHS is false? Or, are some brackets missing?

Comment: A formal proof in which system?

Comment: @Brandon  You should put your work in the Post ...otherwise it looks like you didn't try anything at all and no one is going to help you.  Also, what you did so far looks more like a semantical proof, rather than a formal proof. So .. please very carefully explain in your post exactly what kind of proof you are attempting.

Comment: I nedd a semantical proof

Answer (score 1):

You used semantics in your proof sketch, which is fine. A formal proof however doesn't do this and goes for example along the following lines (in my favorite deduction system for first-order logic):

We assume $\exists xq(x)\lor\neg\exists xp(x)$. (Because $a\rightarrow b\equiv b\lor\neg a$, which can be proved in my favorite deduction system.)
This implies $\exists xq(x)\lor\exists x(\neg p(x))$. (Because $\forall x\phi\rightarrow\exists x\phi$, which can also be proved.)
So, as any of $q(x)$ and $\neg p(x)$ implies $p(x)\rightarrow q(x)$, you can use the introduction and elimination rule for $\exists$ to establish $\exists x(p(x)\rightarrow q(x))$.

Good luck with logic!